# VSCode says [Equal] key is V? Keyboard layout messed up for shortcuts

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I had problems with the Python extension in VSCode. I reinstalled it.

After that, my keyboard shortcuts seemed to be mapped to something completely senseless.

It seems like there is a mapping somewhere that says `[Bracket]` key is the same as `V`?!

How do I fix this?

[image: help]

Comment: I believe it's a bug introduced in 1.75.0 (see discussion https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173325). I hope it's going to be resolved soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue. This seems to be a bug. Here is [the report on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173325).

From [keyboard shortcuts: wrong interpretations of special keys](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173325#issuecomment-1416912603):

> Potential fix [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173456).    The issue was introduced [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/169842).   The
> hashcode for scan codes and simple keys was not updated to distinguish
> between them.

So a PR has been submitted as a potential fix.  It has not been reviewed yet by a team member.  This bug is affecting many people and I would expect it to be included in the v1.75.1 Recovery Release (if the PR is good...).

---

Update:

A PR fix has been merged for this, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/b02d1d580a68554f099a40dc71ed865ecb720f5c.

I assume this will be included in the v1.75.1 Recovery Release soon - or in Insiders 02/06/23.